# Python unicode errors reading files generated by other apps

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8

I'm getting decoding exception errors when reading export files from multiple applications. Have been running into this for a month, as I learn far more about unicode than I ever wanted to know. Some fundamentals are still missing. I understand utf, I understand codepages, I understand how they tend to be used in practice (a single codepage per document e.g., though I can't imagine that's still true today--see the back page of a health statement with 15 languages.)

1. Is it true that utf-8 can and does encode every possible unicode char? How then is it possible for one application to write a utf-8 file and another to not be able to read it?
2. when utf is used, codepages are NOT used, is that correct? as I think it through, the codepage is an older style and is made obsolete by utf. I'm sure there are some exceptions.
3. utf could also be looked as a data compression scheme, less than an encoding one.

But there I'm stuck, as in practice, I have 6 different applications made in different countries, which can create export files, 3 in ut-f, 3 in cp1252, yet python 3.7 cannot read them without error:

'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 1555855: character maps to 
'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 4179683: character maps to

I use Edit Pro to examine the files, which successfully reads the files. It points to a line that contains an extra pair of special double quotes:
"Metro Exodus review: “Not only the best Metro yet, it's one of the best shooters in years” | GamesRadar+"

Removing that ” allows python to continue reading in the file, to the next error.

python reports it as char x9d, but an (really old: Codewright) old editor reports it as x94. Codewright I believe. Verified it is an x94 and x93 pair on the internet so it must be true. ;-)

It is very troublesome that I don't know for sure what the actual bytes are, as there are so many layers of translation, interpretation, format for display, etc.

So the visual studio debug report of x9d is a misdirect. What's going on with the python library that it would report this?

How is this possible? I can find no info about how chars in one codepage can be invalid under utf (if that's the problem). What would I search under?

It should not be this hard. I have 30 years experience in programming c++, sql, you name it, learning new libraries, languages is just breakfast.

I also do not understand why the information to handle this is so hard to find. Surely numerous other programmers doing data conversions, import/exports between applications have run into this for decades.

The files I'm importing are csv files from 6 apps, and json files from another. the 6 apps export in utf-8 and cp1252 (as reported by Edit Pro) and the other app exports json in utf-8, though I could also choose csv.

The 6 apps run on an iPhone and export files I'm attempting to read on windows 10. I'm running python 3.7.8, though this problem has persisted since 3.6.3.

Thanks in advance

Dan

Comment: Hi Dan, it's amazing to have 30+ years of experience in programming. However, you could post a more communicative question by providing your codes so, everyone able to easily understand your goals. Also make sure your question meet the criteria of the [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct).

Answer (score 1):

The error `'charmap' codec can't decode byte...` shows that you are not using utf-8 to read the file. That's the source of your struggles on this one. Unless the file starts with a BOM (byte order mark), you kinda have to know how the file was encoded to decode it correctly.

1. utf-8 encodes all unicode characters and python should be able to read them all. Displaying is another matter. You need font files for the unicode characters to do that part. You were reading in "charmap", not "utf-8" and that's why you had the error.
2. "when utf is used" ... there are several UTF encodings. utf-8, utf-16-be (big endian), utf-16-le (little endian), utf-16 (synonym for utf-16-le), utf-32 variants (I've never seen this in the wild) and variants that include the BOM (byte order mark) which is an optional set of characters at the start of the file describing utf encoding type.

But yes, UTF encodings are meant to replace the older codepage encodings.

3. No, its not compression. The encoded stream could be larger than the bytes needed to hold the string in memory. This is especially true of utf-8, less true with utf-16 (that's why Microsoft went with utf-16). But utf-8 as a superset of ASCII that does not have byte order issues like utf-16 has many other advantages (that's why all the sane people chose it). I can't think of a case where a UTF encoding would ever be smaller than the count of its characters.

Comment: I thought the default was utf8 same as strings. turns out my locale is cp1252. but fixing that did not fix the problem, though it focused it. setting endcoding="utf-8" gives:

Comment: error: "Unexpected UTF-8 BOM (decode using utf-8-sig): line 1 column 1 ". encoding="utf-8-sig" gives the same error message! reading in with a pre-unicode editor shows there is a double BOM 0xEFBBBF at the front of the file! Edit Pro skips over that and opens it correctly as utf-8. I've been trying to investigate this and solve it within python and vs2019. I should have dug out a hex file editor long ago. So far python/vs2019 gets in the way of seeing what is actually being read in. Round tripping coding error probably had to do with the app producing the double BOM, though this was a single.

Comment: @DanJ2754 - You can open the file binary, read a bit and turn that to hex for debug. `open('myfile.txt', 'rb').read(32).hex(' ')`

Comment: 2. in reading literally hundreds of webpages this last month, it was never mentioned that utf-8 should not be used with codepages. Like I say, it should not be this hard! The decision not to tag files at the front with their encoding makes all downstream uses problematic because you never know what was done to create it, or how to use it, and must guess. bad idea to propagate that throughout the coding world.

Comment: That's why the web abores the BOM and any encoding other than utf-8. But utf-16 is preferred by Microsoft - its the new `\r\n`. The various BOMs are in the `codecs` module. You can do your own probing with something like `open('myfile.txt', 'rb').read(10).startswith(codes.BOM_UTF8)` or maybe that utf8 BOM twice now that you've discovered the insanity. There are some python modules on pypi that try to guess encodings - not sure which ones are good.

Comment: There should be a published doc with the tricks to working with encodings in python. and the traps one can fall into, such as converting with a bytes obgject and expecting a str() of it to turn it back to a string. and that charmap actually means codepage. And that there is never a time when a sequence of characters is NOT encoded. it is encoded on disk, encoded (not decoded) in memory (just a possibly different encoding, but always encoded). saying it is decoded implies there is a standard; that standard was ascii. but strings are not ascii; they're utf8 unless you change it. which is weird;

Comment: FYI, Microsoft went with UCS-2 for Windows NT design.  UTF-8 and UTF-16 were invented later.  So they were stuck with backward-compatibility and moved to UTF-16.

Comment: But its perfectly fine to use utf-8 with code pages as long as it all goes through a regular python string first (speaking in python 3, not 2). If I have a file in the Microsoft latin1 CP1252 code page, I could `shutil.copyfileobj(open("codepagefile.txt", encoding="cp1252"), open("fixedfile.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8"))` to normalize it to utf-8. The thing is, I'd have to know that the original was cp1252. If it was a different code page, the decode to unicode would "work" except it would pick the wrong unicode characters.

Comment: what does your default locale do for you then? are strings actually in utf8? if your locale is cp1252? more mess to straighten out-contradictory documentation. pythonic says 1 way to do things. which I agree with. here for sure there are too many exceptions, documentation all over the place. this can be simplified. if every file were marked with its bom/codepage up front, the confusion is immensely reduced; no guessing. I have not found utf8 to be self-explanatory to the python libraries. I agree it doesn't pester me with the info; but it doesn't "just work' either. still have to nitpick it

Comment: every step of the way. the true judge of good software or any machine is does it "just work", thru all special cases, all conditions, overcoming and handling exceptions by itself, rather than halting with cryptic error messages every time there's an exception. and when there is an exception, a full explanation. in round-tripping, lack of bom/duplicate bom is common place and should be reported, certainly in a debugger. but as a warning, not a halt.

Comment: It was all just kind of organic. ASCII defines 0-127 but bytes are 0-255. The bytes are mapped to a font (originally a small bitmap) which displays on the screen. The font table held 256 cells so that you wouldn't have to mask off the upper bit. Non-English computers took advantage of that and added fonts for their particular language. Japan/China/Korea had a bigger problem with nonalphabetic languages and made it more complicated still. Pre-internet, multilanguage docs were rarely shared and you usually had a good idea where they came from.

Comment: 3. by compression I mean that the natural form of unicode characters, where each char is directly addressable by calculation, is in an array of 32 bit cells (or 24 bit if you wanted to implement a 3 byte array (but that takes more time than space). From that natural 32 bit implementation, utf-8 is a compressed form, eliminating the zero bytes, but having an non-constant byte count per character, requiring a byte by byte string traversal to get to the nth char. so when compared to utf-32, the "natural standard", utf-8 is, and its purpose is, compression, to save storage and transmission time.

Comment: Ideally, Microsoft originating files have a BOM of some sort and everyone else is utf-8. Gnerally, protocols should declare encodings. That's done with http, xml, html and etc.

Comment: @DanJ2754 Python juggles 1, 2 and 4 byte variants in its `str` class. Isn't `wchar_t` 4 bytes on linuxy gcc things but 2 bytes on microsoft visual studio? I can't remember! But I'm pretty sure that microsoft was doing usc-2 in core, at least back in the day.

Comment: And getting back to the double utf-8 BOMs in the file. Whatever wrote that file made a mistake. There should only be one. If that happens to be internal code for you, it would be good to fix it.

Comment: 4. how does unicode manage its numbered, assigned character range? there are something like 114,000 characters assigned in a 1.1 million character range. are they all grouped together in 0-113,999 or are the spread out across the greater range, perhaps grouped together with each group starting at a particular boundary/starting number? In trying to understand the read failures, I realized a sequence could be written out (outside of a proven api) in binary, which if the assigned char range were not packed together, there would be gaps where

Comment: legitimate 32 bit numbers were not actually equal to an assigned char. a sparse array.

Comment: @DanJ2754 - they are spread out and there is a lookup process when displaying. When simply manipulating the strings in a program, they are just bytes.... mostly. There are still multi-codepoint sequences that compose a single character, and other oddities. If you really want to compare strings safely, you can `unicodedata.normalize()` them first.

Comment: Unicode is hard, but then somehow we've managed to unify hundreds of languages, mathematical symbols, musical notation, … emojis ([charts](http://www.unicode.org/charts/index.html))! Its pretty amazing. Good reads are on [unicode.org](https://home.unicode.org/), [readthedocs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) and 
[wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode).